# How to clear Windows clipboard using a batch file or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, clipboard

I have a batch file and my program works automatically with the clipboard.

But I want to clear the clipboard and used this:

```
echo>nul|clip
```

Is there any other method for clearing Windows clipboard?

Comment: What about `< nul clip`?

Comment: `break|clip`(Clears text in clipboard; if there is a picture (or probably any object besides text) there's no effect)  (@aschipfl your's doesn't work (surprisingly))

Comment: What?? does `rem/ | clip` work then? (can't test at the moment, I'm on mobile)

Comment: @aschipfl: sorry, no: `Der Befehl "rem/" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.` (just `rem/` without piping works)

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan! `(rem/) | clip` will work then; it's absolutely illogical that `< nul clip` fails, what a terrible design!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the most logical approach (at least in my opinion), that is to [redirect](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) (`<`) nothing (`nul`) to *STDIN* (handle `0`) to the `clip` command, like `< nul clip`, does not work due to a terrible design of that command, because it seems that input redirection (`<`) can only be done with files.

So a pipe (`|`) needs to be used, which still allows several ways:

```cmd
echo/> nul | clip

break | clip

(rem/) | clip

type nul | clip

goto | clip

call | clip

exit | clip
```

All of the above methods use a command on the left side of the pipe that do not output anything to *STDOUT* (handle `1`).

Comment: When using powershell, none of above commads works. We should use cmd to run those commands.

Comment: Yes, @ToughMind, this is code for [tag:cmd] or [tag:batch-file] just like the one in the question; other answers already provide [tag:powershell] solutions...

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to do it. This appears to clear at least CF_TEXT and CF_BITMAP. Needs testing to see if it clears all CF_* types.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Set-Clipboard -Value $null"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it with Powershell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Batch**

Some more ways in batch:

```
<nul set /p="" | clip
dir >nul | clip 
cd %cd% | clip
pushd %cd% | clip
cd >nul | clip
```

**VBscript**

A method in VBscript:

```
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate("about:blank")
IE.Document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", ""
IE.Quit
```